# How to send copy email to embedded signer in docusign with "embeddedRecipientStartURL":"SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN" method php?

Tags: php, docusignapi

I want to Send an copy Email using this method embeddedRecipientStartURL":"SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN".
can you elaborate more?

Comment: you are the one that needs to " elaborate more"

Comment: You would get faster answers on the DocuSign forum or support team. They reply fast.

Comment: Can you please explain more, you want to use embedded signing and want to send the completed envelope to the embedded signer?

Comment: I want to copy email from DocuSign  how we can send the email using embeddedRecipientStartURL function . can anybody let me know how we can define the function and send the copy of contract to signer.

Comment: Still we cannot get what you want, do you want to use embedded signing and also want to send initial email to the embedded signer so that embedded signer can start the signing process from the email? or do you want to know whats the use of `embeddedRecipientStartURL`?

Comment: do you want to use embedded signing and also want to send initial email to the embedded signer so that embedded signer can start the signing process from the email? 


Comment :-yes 

@AmitKBist

Answer (score 1):

If you set `clientUserId` for a signer then you are explicitly saying to DocuSign that this signer should be an embedded signer. Now once a signer becomes embedded signer then by default, DocuSign does not send any email to the embedded signer.

Now, when using `embeddedRecipientStartURL` option, the embedded recipient still receives an email from DocuSign, just as a remote recipient would. When the document link in the email is clicked the recipient is redirected, through DocuSign, to the supplied URL to complete their actions. When routing to the URL, the sender's system (the server responding to the URL) must request a recipient token to launch a signing session.

If sender sets `embeddedRecipientStartURL` to `SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN`, the recipient is directed to an embedded signing or viewing process directly hosted at DocuSign. The signing or viewing action is initiated by the DocuSign system and the transaction activity and Certificate of Completion records will reflect this.

Sample Request JSON will look like below:

```
{
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [{
                    "tabs": {
                        "fullNameTabs": [{
                            "fontColor": "white",
                            "pageNumber": 1,
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "xPosition": 400,
                            "yPosition": 15
                        }]
                    },
                    "name": "Full Name",
                    "email": "signersemail@email.com",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "clientUserId": "1000",
                    "embeddedRecipientStartURL": "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN"
                }]
            },
            "sequence": "1"
        }],
        "document": {
            "documentBase64": "<Base64Bytes>",
            "documentId": "1",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "name": "Doc.pdf"
        }
    }],
    "status": "sent",
    "emailBlurb": "Test Body",
    "emailSubject": "Test Subject"
}
```

Comment: Can you let me how we can setup this function?

Comment: I have added code in my answer to show you how to set `embeddedRecipientStartURL`

Comment: i am using php library how we can use into it .

Comment: I will  not be able to develop PHP code for you but you can try `https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/src/Model/Signer.php` there is a property `embedded_recipient_start_url` to set this value.

Comment: i am just confuse about where i need to define the embedded_recipient_start_url in our code . If you help me out that will be god for me @amit

Comment: I am not a PHP developer so cannot write a code for you. You need to add signer to an envelope and `embedded_recipient_start_url`  needs to be set in the `Signer` class. If you check `signatureRequestOnDocument()` method in  `https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/master/test/UnitTests.php` then you can change it like `if($embeddedSigning) {
    $signer->setClientUserId($testConfig->getClientUserId());
    $signer->setEmbeddedRecipientStartUrl($testConfig->getEmbeddedRecipientStartUrl());
   }`